# Why using Comment in sql doesnt return any row?

Tags: php, sql

Im reading book about **sql injection** , and theres an example about " How to use comments to bypass the authentication " :

sql code :

```
select * from users where username = '' AND password = '' ;
```

and other comments : # or -- are filtered , so we just can use /**/ :

the sql code after use comment :

```
select * from users where username = 'admin' /* ' AND password = '*/'' ;
```

and will return

```
select * from users where username = 'admin'''
```

and login , but thats what book is wrote , but when i test it in my login , its doesn't work .

-PS: i test it in phpmyadmin & sql-server management  , and doesnt work , 
so is the book wrong ? or im doing it wrong ? and if so what is the correct way to do that using /**/ ?

Comment: When you use Prepared Statements there is no way of bypassing queries. So don't bother.

Comment: just use one ' character

Comment: I think this is a valid question when studying – but as mentioned in the comments, you should not find yourself in this position when making something for real-world use.

Comment: Your query (unquoted) results in `select * from users where username = admin'` (`''` will appear as a single `'` hence your inability to log in because `admin' <> admin`). anyway I suggest you to use 'canned programs' to perform logons or just to remove special characters (server side) on strings passed

Comment: @juergend yea i know , but i want to test what book wrote ,

Comment: @ErangaGamagedara will not work , i need to escape my comment

Comment: @ThomasEdwards i want to learn it , so i need to practice my self

Comment: @DDS i dont understand you bro , can u explain more ?

Comment: @justlearn2 apostroph character in SQL is used both for string delimiting and for character escaping, so if you want to put the string *I'm lazy* you have to write: `DECLARE @var varchar(100) set @var = 'I''m lazy' select @var` (the exemplum works on SQL SERVER). note the double `'` for the apostroph after *I*. The query will give as result *I'm Lazy*

Answer (score 1):

You’ve added an extra `'`.

```
select * from users where username = '' AND password = ''
```

Could be changed to:

```
select * from users where username = 'admin /*' AND password = '*/'
```

This would then return:

```
select * from users where username = 'admin'
```

Comment: this is not true , i add ' to escape the comment , so what u do will not work ,

Comment: You don’t need to escape comments

Comment: i did what you wrote, but it doesnt work , i test it in phpmyadmin .
 MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0000 seconds.)

Comment: Do you have a user with the username `admin` in your database? It’s hard to work out the context here because I don’t know what the book says, so probably not the right place to figure this out.

Comment: yea i have an valid user = admin , and i already know that i need to use ' for escape my code , im sure about it . so ur solution will not work .. thanks .